AtomicLong shared between threads?
I have a two threads share an instance of AtomicLong.
First thread only increments, while the second thread only decrements.
Two threads guarded by a Lock and a Condition.
With the following shared values,
final var lock = new ReentrantLock();
final var condition = lock.newCondition();
final var accumulated = new AtomicLong(); // accumulated <n> from <request(n)>

The first thread only increments the atomic variable.
// Thread 1
void doSome(final long n) {
    try {
        lock.lock();
        if (accumulated.addAndGet(n) < 0L) { // overflowed
            accumulated.set(Long.MAX_VALUE); // > effectively unbounded
        }
        condition.signal();
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}


While the second thread only decrements the atomic variable.
// Thread 2
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

    lock.lock();
    try {
        while (accumulated.get() == 0L) {
            try {
                condition.await();
            } catch (final InterruptedException ie) {
                log.info("interrupted while awaiting the condition", ie);
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                break;
            }
        }

        while (accumulated.getAndDecrement() > 0L) { // -
             // do some                              //  |
        }                                            //  |
                                                     //  |
    } finally {                                      //  |
        lock.unlock();                               //  |
    }                                                //  |
                                                     //  |
                                                     //  |
    //while (accumulated.getAndDecrement() > 0L) { // <-- Can(Should) I move the while loop to here?
    //     // do some
    // }

}

My question is that can I relocate the while loop which decrements the atomic variable outside the lock idiom?

I'm not sure I understand what your threads are trying to do but I'm wondering if a semaphore might be more suitable for your needs.

So the lock is mostly meant to make the overflow handling atomic? In that case I'd say you need to keep the loop inside the locked area - or try and find another way to make the overflow handling atomic without locking everywhere. You might also want to consider only locking when you access the integer, i.e. inside the loop condition and body. Also, would "effectively unbounded" mean you'd still want to decrement? Can those numbers even get that high?

Are you sure you need to check for overflow? Even if you increment the AtomicLong by 1 every nanosecond, it will take you 27 years to overflow.

addAndGet and set are called separately, thereby making it a non-atomic operation. Another thread can now see a negative value. accumulateAndGet is a better option, as there you can perform the replacement of an overflowed value inside the atomic operation.

What are you solving for? What is the point of the code? Why do you want to change it? Is it incorrect? Is it too slow? Is there some other reason? The pasted code is difficult to understand and looks like a complicated solution to what might be a simple problem (protect concurrent access to a shared member).
